# powershell - concatenate N text files and prepend filename to each line

Tags: powershell, text

Powershell - easy question.

I want to concatenate N text files and prepend filename to each line.  How to do same but have full path+filename?  Each files should retain all text and line terminators as-is.

**data1.txt**

```
this is the text in
data1 file - hello
```

**data2.txt**

```
four score and
seven years ago
```

To get this file

**output.txt**

```
data1.txt: this is the text in
data1.txt: data1 file - hello
data2.txt: four score and
data2.txt: seven years ago
```

It will be something like this - but that actually works.

get-content c:\temp\data*.txt|foreach-object{$tmp=get-content $*;$*.basename+","+$tmp} > output.txt

Thanks

Comment: I should include that I am using Powershell ISE in Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
$path = "c:\temp"
$out  = "c:\temp\output.txt"

Get-ChildItem $path -Filter data*.txt | % {
    $file = $_.Name
    Get-Content $_.FullName | % {
        "${file}: $_" | Out-File -Append $out
    }
}
```

Comment: nice answer, but it can fail if the current working directory isn't c:\temp.  `Get-Content $_.FullName` might be a little more robust.

Comment: @Matt Thanks Matt! I've updated the answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select-String '^' data*.txt >output.txt
```

If you don't want the line numbers, remove them like this:

```
(Select-String '^' data*.txt) -replace '^([^:]*:)\d+:','$1' >output.txt
```

**Edit:** If you want just the filename without the path you could remove a leading path along with the line number like this:

```
(Select-String '^' data*.txt) -replace '^(.:[^:]*\\)?([^:]*:)\d+:','$2' >output.txt
```

or you could construct the output from the properties of the `MatchInfo` objects `Select-String` produces:

```
Select-String '^' data*.txt | % { "{0}:{1}" -f $_.Filename, $_.Line } >output.txt
```

Comment: (Select-String '^' $input) -replace '([^:]*:)\d+:','$1' > $output    leaving off one '^' did the trick.

Comment: but how to strip off the path?

Comment: Thanks Ansgar but I must be missing something.  None of the syntax above leaves off the path for me.

Comment: There was a mistake in the 3rd code sample (fixed now), but the 4th one should work just fine. Please provide evidence if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
ls c:\temp\data*.txt | foreach-object { $fname=[System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($_); get-content $_ | foreach-object { echo $fname": "$_ >> output.txt}}
```

Just make sure you delete output.txt if you need to run it again or if new data needs to be added.

inputs used from above, output.txt:

```
PS C:\> cat .\temp\output.txt
data1.txt: this is the text in
data1.txt: data1 file - hello
data2.txt: four score and
data2.txt: seven years ago
```