# Merge Text Files and Prepend Filename and Line Number - Powershell

Tags: powershell, text, powershell-3.0

I've been trying to adapt the answer to this question: [powershell - concatenate N text files and prepend filename to each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724617/powershell-concatenate-n-text-files-and-prepend-filename-to-each-line)

My desired output based on an example of 2 .txt files:

**First.txt**

lines of

data

**Second.txt**

more lines

of

data

**Output.txt**

First1 lines of

First2 data

Second1 more lines

Second2 of

Second3 data

Based on the most similar question I could find the following answer:

```
Select-String '^' *.txt >output.txt
```

Would give:

C:\A\Filepath\First.txt:1:lines of

C:\A\Filepath\First.txt:2:data

C:\A\Filepath\Second.txt:1:more lines

C:\A\Filepath\Second.txt:2:of

C:\A\Filepath\Second.txt:3:data

So I was hoping to use -replace to remove the filepath, keep the file name (but remove .txt:), keep the line number (but replace the final : with a space) and keep the text from the line.

Any help would be appreciated reaching the desired output.txt. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not beautiful but this is one approach.

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt |
%{$FILENAME=$_.BaseName;$COUNT=1;get-content $_ |
%{"$FILENAME"+"$COUNT"+" " + "$_";$COUNT++}}|
Out-File Output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, it works well, although I found it interesting that the file sizes that were created for what looks like identical results to Matt's approach were always around double.

Comment: That's because Out-File creates the file in UTF16. You can create ascii file  like this "out-file C:\temp\out.txt -Encoding ascii"

Answer (score 1):

The `select-string` approach is very interesting. The way I would go about it is to use `Get-Content`. The advantage there is that each line has a `readcount` property that represents the line number.

```psh
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\*.file" | ForEach-Object{
    $fileName = $_.BaseName
    Get-content $_ | ForEach-Object{
        "{0}{1} {2}" -f $fileName,$_.ReadCount,$_
    }
} | Add-Content "C:\temp\output.txt"
```

Take each file and use `Get-Content`. With each line we process we send to the output stream a formatted line matching your desired output. No need to count the lines as `$_.ReadCount` already knows.

**Select-String still works**

You just need to manipulate the output to match what you want. Using `Get-Member` we can check the properties of what `select-string` returns to get our desired output.

```psh
Select-String '^' "c:\temp\*.txt" | ForEach-Object{
    "{0}{1} {2}" -f $_.Filename,$_.LineNumber,$_.Line
} | Add-Content "C:\temp\output.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll go with the Get-ChildItem approach as I'm not attached to any method in particular just whichever works and then works fastest. The Select-String approach leaves .txt in. It has no $_.BaseName in, which might be why, but I tried mimicking the top one except used $_.Filename = $_.BaseName and it gave a ReadOnly property error when running.